How I can make the aws codepipeline to auto-create the nessesary roles?
I made a Pipeline using terraform:
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "test_staging_app" {
  compute_platform = "Server"
  name             = "test"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_codebuild_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codebuild.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_staging_codepipeline_role" {
  name               = "test_staging_codepipeline_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_staging_codepipeline_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_staging_codepipeline_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codepipeline.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_staging_codebuild_role" {
  name               = "test_staging_app_codebuild_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_codebuild_role_policy.json
}


resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "test_staging_app_dg" {
  deployment_group_name="test_staging"
  app_name = aws_codedeploy_app.test_staging_app.name
  service_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::962331388720:role/EC2CodeployIntanceRole" 

  ec2_tag_set {  
    ec2_tag_filter {
      key   = "Name"
      type  = "KEY_AND_VALUE"
      value = "test_staging"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "test_build_staging" {
  name          = "test_build_staging"
  description   = "Example CodeBuild project"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.test_staging_codebuild_role.arn
  environment {
    compute_type    = "BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:7.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  source {
    type            = "CODEPIPELINE"
    location        = "example-pipeline"
    buildspec       = "buildspec.yml"
  }
}

resource "aws_codepipeline" "test_staging_codepipeline" {
  name     = "test_staging"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.test_staging_codepipeline_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    location = "codepipeline-eu-west-1-255928215117"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["source_output"]

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn    = "arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-west-1:962331388720:connection/c93ae8ec-e07c-4720-9961-bdb3ab58386d"
        FullRepositoryId = "dummyrepo"
        BranchName       = "test_aws"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts  = ["source_output"]
      output_artifacts = ["build_output"]
      version          = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName = aws_codebuild_project.test_build_staging.name
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
        name            = "Deploy"
        category        = "Deploy"
        owner           = "AWS"
        provider        = "CodeDeploy"
        input_artifacts = ["build_output"]
        version         = "1" 

        configuration = {
            ApplicationName  = aws_codedeploy_app.test_staging_app.name
            DeploymentGroupName = aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.test_staging_app_dg.deployment_group_name
        }
    }
  }
}

But upon pushing into dummyrepo into test_aws branch I get the error in Codepipeline.
Unable to use Connection: arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-west-1:962331388720:connection/c93ae8ec-e07c-4720-9961-bdb3ab58386d. The provided role does not have sufficient permissions.

So how I can make the terraform to automatically create a role with nesessary permissions like AWS Console does?
Usually, aws web console allows to create the nessesary roles for itself but I see no option upon terraform documentation.

It seems you're only creating a trust policy, i.e, you are allowing CodeDeploy/CodeBuild to assume the role, but you are not assigning any permissions policy. In other words, the service role can be assumed but cannot do anything after it has been assumed. You can read more in the AWS docs.
